# MatrixGestureDetector set to identity

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am using [MatrixGestureDetector](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector) to set a matrix:

```
...
onMatrixUpdate: (Matrix4 m, Matrix4 tm, Matrix4 sm, Matrix4 rm) {
            setState(() {
              matrix = MatrixGestureDetector.compose(m, null, null, null);
...
```

Then in another function I set the same matrix to:

```
matrix = Matrix4.identity();
```

Now when onMatrixUpdate in MatrixGestureDetector is called again, the matrix is out of place with the `Matrix4.identity()` is there a way to set MatrixGestureDetector to identity?

Thanks to @pskink I tried this in the same function where I do `matrix = Matrix4.identity();`:

```
matrix = MatrixGestureDetector.compose(matrix, translateMatrix, scaleMatrix, null);
```

Comment: see https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/transform_demo2.dart

Comment: Do you know how to set the internal matrix of MatrixGestureDetector?

Comment: you dont set internal matrix, did you see the code i posted? from `onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm)` you use `tm`, `sm` and `rm`

Comment: Yes, thanks - but I dont see how I can make MatrixGestureDetector use the same offset after doing Matrix4.identity(). I just tried: matrix = MatrixGestureDetector.compose(null, null, null, null); Hoping it would set its internal

Comment: https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/transform_demo2.dart#L40

Comment: Hmm not working for me... It keeps the last onMatrixUpdate values.  I will try to update my question.

Comment: `MatrixGestureDetector.compose` method is working just fine

Comment: Hi @pskink I wrapped it in a AnimatedBuilder and it works - thanks for replying. Is it you who made the MatrixGestureDetector? If so, well done!

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
matrix = MatrixGestureDetector.compose(matrix, tm, sm, null);
```

Does work as suggested, I just needed to wrap the Transformation widget in an AnimatedBuilder and use ValueNotifier.